# Running Out of Heap Memory Trying to Push a Single Character to Stack in Java

Tags: java, memory, stack, heap-memory

I'm trying to make an infix to expression tree program for school in Java, to do so I am trying to implement a postfix queue which is constructed after being passed an infix String, inside of this queue I am using the Java Stack to hold onto operators and left parenthesis for the shunting-yard algorithm, the expression tree has to use generic nodes to hold char/int.

When my program tries to push the first '(' encountered, I am encountering a heap memory error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3511)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3480)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.grow(Vector.java:262)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.grow(Vector.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.add(Vector.java:782)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.addElement(Vector.java:617)
    at java.base/java.util.Stack.push(Stack.java:66)
    at project01/project1.PostfixQueue.<init>(PostfixQueue.java:128)
    at project01/project1.ExpressionTree.<init>(ExpressionTree.java:22)
    at project01/project1.Driver.main(Driver.java:11)"
```

```
    public PostfixQueue(String infix) {
    Stack<Character> opStack = new Stack<Character>();
    PostfixQueue postQueue = new PostfixQueue();
    
    
    Character digit;
    int numDigits = 0, result = 0;
    
    while(infix.length() > 0) {
        
        digit = (Character) infix.charAt(0);
        
        switch(digit) {
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        case '0':
            if(numDigits > 0) {
                result = (result * 10) + Character.getNumericValue(digit); //if a result int is previously stored (multi digit int in the string)
                
                if(infix.charAt(1) >= 48 && infix.charAt(1) <= 57) {
                    numDigits++;
                    
                }
                else {
                    //output result
                    postQueue.Enqueue(result);
                    
                    numDigits = 0; //reset numDigits
                }
                
                
            }
            else if(numDigits == 0) {
                if(infix.charAt(1) >= 48 && infix.charAt(1) <= 57) { //If next input is a number w/o whitespace (ex: 45)
                    numDigits++;
                    
                    result = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
                }
                else {
                    numDigits = 0; //reset numDigits
                    
                    //output result
                    postQueue.Enqueue(result);
                }
                
                
            } //End else if
            break;
            
        case '+':
        case '-':
            if(opStack.empty() || opStack.peek() == '(')
            {
                opStack.push(digit);
            }
            else{
                while(opStack.peek() == '+' || opStack.peek() == '-' || opStack.peek() == '*' || opStack.peek() == '/') {
                    //Pop operator and queue it
                    postQueue.Enqueue(opStack.pop());
                    
                }// end while
            }// end else
            opStack.push(digit);
            break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            while(opStack.peek() == '*' || opStack.peek() == '/') {
                //Pop operator and queue it
                postQueue.Enqueue(opStack.pop());
            }//end while
            opStack.push(digit);
            break;
        case '(':
            opStack.push(digit);
            break;
        case ')':
            while(opStack.peek() != '(') {
                //Pop operator and queue it
                postQueue.Enqueue(opStack.pop());
            }// end while
            
            opStack.pop();
            
            break;
        } // End Switch Statement           
        infix.substring(1);
        
    } // End While Statement            
    this.first = postQueue.GetFirst();
    } // End Constructor
```

'''

The error occurs at "opStack.push(digit)"

The variable for the top error statement line 3511 is:
copyOf() is throwing    OutOfMemoryError  (id=20)

How can I fix this so that I can actually test if the logic throughout the rest of the class and other classes works?

Comment: `PostfixQueue postQueue = new PostfixQueue();` appears to be recursive. You are constructing a `PostfixQueue` and doing so requires constructing another one. That is probably a problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - there's no "probably" about it :-)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How can I fix this? When I comment out that line and try to use the class methods in the constructor without it I get errors stating "The method "Enqueue(T) in the type PostfixQueue<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Character). I had to learn Java in the last couple weeks for this project and it has to use generics which are not a concept I've learned in class or in the languages I know

Comment: Do not put all the logic in a constructor. You have not posted enough code for us to really help beyond generalities. And at the same time, you have posted too much code. In that you dumped a single huge constructor and called it good enough.

Comment: Not sure where else I would put the logic other than my non-default constructor, and I also have a default constructor which the line "PostfixQueue postQueue = new PostfixQueue();" should be using so I'm still not sure how it was recursive to begin with? And also the error is occurring well after that line, the error occurs at the push statement of "case '(':
            opStack.push(digit);"

Comment: Aside: [*the `Deque` interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Comment: @user16632363 Nope. There is no recursion. The queue inside the constructor uses a different constructor. And you can see from the stack trace that there is no infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I wasn't changing my loop condition by accident, down near the bottom the line `infix.substring(1);` should have been `infix = infix.substring(1);`, my program was trying to create an infinite stack of left parentheses.